Can :has pseudo-class be nested in :is pseudo-class?
Can :has be nested in :is? Both :has and :is MDN articles don't cover nesting.
I have the following code (it changes opacity, when a container is hovered or contains a tabbed element):
*:is(:hover, :has(:focus-visible)) > .code-toolbar > button
{
    opacity: 0.4;
}

It seems it perfectly works in the latest Chrome, but LESS says: Missing closing ')'.
UPD This is a LESS issue.

Yes. :has cannot be nested inside :has, but :has inside :is is fine.

Hello @Alohci, thank you, but why then I cannot compile a .less file with this selector? It's a bug in less.js?

Probably a bug in LESS, yes.

@Alohci It is.
